# Nice exponential equation by SyberMath: $2^{x^2}\cdot5^x=10$

Tags: solution-verification, logarithms, exponentiation

So I was looking through the homepage of Youtube to see if there were any math equations that I thought that I might be able to solve when I came across [this](https://youtu.be/nYqZZEKbZrU) video by SyberMath finding the value of $x$ in $$2^{x^2}\cdot5^x=10$$ which I thought that I might be able to do. Here is my attempt at solving the aforementioned equation:$$2^{x^2}\cdot5^x=10$$$$2^{x^2}5^{x^2}5^{x^2-x}=10$$$$\dfrac{2^{x^2}5^{x^2}5^{x^2}}{5^x}=10$$$$\dfrac{50^{x^2}}{5^x}=10$$$$50^{x^2}=5^x10$$$$x^2\ln50=x\ln5+\ln10$$$$x\ln50=\ln5+\dfrac{\ln10}x$$$$x\ln50-\ln5=\require{cancel}\cancel{\ln5-\ln5}+\dfrac{\ln10}x-\ln5$$$$x\ln10=\dfrac{\ln2}x$$$$x^2\ln10=\ln2$$$$x^2=\dfrac{\ln2}{\ln10}\qquad\text{The reason being if I had subtracted that}$$$$\text{it would have resulted in }(x^2-1)\ln10=-\ln5$$$$x=\sqrt{\dfrac{\ln2}{\ln10}}$$

---

---

#### My question

---

---

Is the solution that I have arrived at correct, or what could I do to attain the correct solution more easily/attain it more quickly?

---

---

##### Mistakes I might have made

---

---

1. Logarithms
2. Exponentiation (ties into logarithms)
3. Basically everything

Comment: Have you tried to verify your solution by substituting it in the original equation?

Comment: @MartinR Yes, however I seem to be getting stuck for some reason.

Comment: It seems to be that at one point you subtract $\ln 5$ once on the left-hand side, and twice on the right-hand side.

Comment: $5^{x^2}\cdot 5^{x^2-x}=5^{2x^2-x}\neq 5^x.$ You want $5^{x^2}\cdot 5^{x-x^2}=5^x.$

Comment: @MartinR oh ah welp I do seem to make a lot of mistakes when dealing with logarithms

Comment: @Thomas Andrews ah okay I'll try to remember that

Comment: Just take the logarithm of the initial equation. That gives you a quadratic equation for $x$, which can be solved with standard methods.

Comment: Hopefully you noticed that $1$ is a solution.

Comment: @Karl I did, I just wanted to see if there were any more solutions :\

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$2^{x^2}5^x=10$
By inspection can see that 1 is a solution.  Are there others?

Take the log of both sides (the base doesn't technically matter, but base 10 seems to be what the problem was designed for.)

$\log(2^{x^2})+\log (5^x) = 1\\
(\log 2)x^2 + (\log 5) x - 1 = 0$

Now we have a quadratic.

Rather than using the quadratic formula, we can use the fact that we know that 1 is a root.  By Vieta's formulas, we know that $r_1r_2 = \frac {c}{a}$ and $r_1+r_2 = -\frac ba.$  And, the other root must be $-\frac {1}{\log 2} = -(\frac {\log 5}{\log 2} + 1) = -\log_2 10$

Answer (score 2):

Quite a neat way is to write $10=2\cdot5$ and divide both sides by this, getting $$2^{x^2-1}\cdot5^{x-1}=1,$$ or $$\left(2^{x+1}\cdot 5 \right)^{x-1}=1.$$ Then either $x=1$ or $2^{x+1}\cdot 5=1$. The latter is $2^x=\frac{1}{10}$, or $x=-\dfrac{\ln10}{\ln2}$.

Comment: Good answer ! (+1)

Answer (score 1):

The quadratic equation shown by other posters also comes about from applying the properties of exponents:
$$ 2^{x^2}·5^x \ \ = \ \ 2^{x·x}·5^x \ \ = \ \ (2^x)^x·5^x \ \ = \ \ (2^x·5)^x \ \ = \ \ 10 $$
$$ \Rightarrow \ \ x·\log_a(2^x·5) \ \ = \ \ x·(\log_a 2^x \ + \ \log_a 5) \ \ = \ \ x·(x·\log_a 2  \ + \ \log_a 5) $$ $$ = \ \  (\log_a 2)·x^2  \ + \ (\log_a 5)·x \ \ = \ \ \log_a 10 \ \ . $$

This can then be factored as
$$ (\log_a 2)·x·x \ + \ \left(\log_a \frac{10}{2} \right)·x \  − \ \log_a 10 $$ $$ =  \ \ x·(\log_a 2)·x \ + \ (\log_a 10)·x \ − \ (\log_a 2)·x \ − \ \log_a 10 $$
$$ =  \ \ (x \ − \  1)·( \ [\log_a 2]·x \ + \ \log_a 10 \ ) \ \ = \ \ 0 \ \ . $$

We should expect the original equation to have two roots.  The function $ \ a^{x^2} \ \ , \ a \ > \ 1 \ \ $  is an even function with a global minimum at $ \ (0 \ , \ 1) \ \ ; \ $ so, for instance, $ \ 2^{x^2} \ = \ 10 \ \Rightarrow \ x \ = \ \pm \sqrt{\frac{\log_a 10}{\log_a 2}} \ \ .  \ $  The function used in our equation can be written as
$$ 2^{x^2}·(2^{\log_2 5})^x \ \ = \ \ 2^{x^2 \ + \ \log_2 5·x} \ \ = \ \ 2^{( \ x  \ + \ [\log_2 5]/2 \ )^2}·2^{-[\log_2 5]^2/4} \ \ ,  $$
which "shifts" $ \ 2^{x^2} \ $ "to the left" by $ \ \frac{\log_2 5}{2} \ \approx \ 1.1610 \ $ and "compresses it vertically" by a factor of $ \ 2^{-[\log_2 5]^2/4} \ \approx \ 2^{-1.3478} \ \approx \ 0.3929 \ \ . \ $  The function curve retains the convex ("concave upward") shape of $ \ 2^{x^2} \ \ $ with the indicated axis of symmetry and global minimum; it also continues to have a $ \ y-$intercept $ \ (0 \ , \ 1) \ \ . \ $  The equation $ \ 2^{x^2}·5^x \ = \ c \ $ thus has two solutions, one positive and one negative, for $ \ c \ > \ 2^{-[\log_2 5]^2/4} \ \ . $

The roots for $ \ c \ = \ 10 \ $ would be found from this expression as
$$ \left( \ x  \ + \ \frac{\log_2 5}{2} \ \right)^2  \ - \ \frac{(\log_2 5)^2}{4}  \ \ = \ \ \log_2 10 $$ $$ \Rightarrow \ \ \left( \ x  \ + \ \frac{\log_2 5}{2} \ \right)^2    \ \ = \ \ \frac{4·\log_2 10 \ + \ (\log_2 5)^2}{4} \ \ = \ \ \frac{4·[ \ \log_2 5 \ + \ \log_2 2 \ ] \ + \ (\log_2 5)^2}{4} $$
$$ = \ \ \frac{(\log_2 5)^2 \ + \ 4·  \log_2 5 \ + \ 4 \ }{4} \ \ = \ \ \frac{ ( \ \log_2 5   \ + \ 2 \ )^2 }{4} $$

$$ \Rightarrow \ \  \ x  \ + \ \frac{\log_2 5}{2}     \ \ = \ \  \pm \left( \frac{  \log_2 5   \ + \ 2   }{2} \right) \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ x \ \ = \ \ 1 \ \ , \ \ -1 \ - \ \log_2 5 \ \ \approx \ \ -3.3219 \ \ . $$

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
2^{\log_2(10)}=10=2^{x^2}5^x=2^{x^2}2^{\log_2(5)x}=2^{x^2+\log_2(5)x}
&\Longrightarrow \log_2(10)=x^2+\log_2(5)x\\
&\Longrightarrow x^2+\log_2(5)x-\log_2(10)=0.
\end{align}

Now, the solution is by completing squares.

Answer (score 0):

Take $\ln$ of both sides and obtain the quadratic equation
$$(\ln2)x^2+(\ln5)x-\ln 10=0.$$
Then solve by factoring
$$(x-1)(x\ln2+\ln10)=0.$$